# Sql Server 2008 Reporting Services email on the fly solution

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

To all,

I have noticed that other reporting tools allow you the option, at the time of running a report from the web interface, to either have it rendered to the browser or allow you to enter an email address have have the report sent to that address.  This would be helpful for long running reports or reports that are fairly large.

My question is whether this can be done with the existing sql server 2008 report server toolset or if there are third part solutions available?

Thanks.

--sean

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that what you are wanting to do is possible out of the box.

This may seem like overkill for your situation, however, I have worked for a client who wanted some custom features like this.  Given that Report Manager is so inflexible out of the box, we wrote a new front end leveraging the Reporting Services Service.  We could then write our own extended capabilities right into the new viewer.

This link describes it a bit more.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159218.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a subscription on a report which will email it too you once or at regular intervals.

This [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160334.aspx) give you more info. Be aware that if you want data driven subscriptions you need enterprise sql server.

Comment: We have enterprise and we use that feature for our scheduled reports.  What I want is the ability for someone to go to a report URL, make some parameter choices, and when they hit the run report button have the option to wait for the report to finish or tell the system to send them the results via email.  This should all be dynamic.